# logging in to linux from grub

Tags: grub2, gnome, xmonad

Long story short: I used xmonad gnome and no keycombination will work to launch a terminal (I tried everything I found on the web). So now I think enough experimenting for today I would like to back to gnome. So I reboot. I get the GNU GRUB menu and I continue to ubuntu. However my system is setup is such a way that it continues to the previously used desktop manager: Xmonad gnome. Which doesn't react to any key combination. I just get the black screen with no cursor...
Can't I login to ubuntu from the grub command line (just tabbing c) and start up the regular gnome desktop manager? How can I do this? Or do you guys have a better idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hold Shift(CAUTION:this will not work in a UEFI+MBR combination)
Delete `quiet splash` out of your kernel line and instead type this in: `init=/bin/bash`. This will give a usable `root` shell in relatively simple setups.(No RAID, no encrypted `/usr`, rootfs and `/etc` can be reached without help of `network-manager`). type in `dpkg-reconfigure -a`.

Comment: I should press shift will I'm booting, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, right after the `POST` when `GRUB loading` screen comes.